# Azure SQL Database Usage from REST API

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-sql-database

I'd like to retrieve the usage details for a SQL Database from Azure Service Management REST API.

Usage details is available for websites but I cannot find any REST services to get the usage details(deadlocks, failed connections etc.). As of now, I can get the basic details about the database and its properties. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn720371.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to query the system database for this information.. check following MSDN documentation for plenty of details -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270018(v=sql.120).aspx

sys.event_log

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj819229.aspx#EventTypes

Event Types (includes `connection_failed` and `deadlock`)

Example from the first link -

`select * from sys.event_log where event_type='deadlock' and database_name='Database1'`